# Error while compiling opentsDB for Cassandra using AsyncCassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, opentsdb

I am  following  below link to build AsyncCassandra -

https://github.com/OpenTSDB/asynccassandra

But I am getting following error :

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /root/asynccassandra/src/org/hbase/async/HBaseClient.java:[304,34]     error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   variable ConsistencyLevel
location: class HBaseClient
/root/asynccassandra/src/org/hbase/async/HBaseClient.java:[303,25] [deprecation] BoundedExponentialBackoff(long,int,int) in BoundedExponentialBackoff has been deprecated
[ERROR] /root/asynccassandra/src/org/hbase/async/HBaseClient.java:[311,35] error: cannot find symbol
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like source code is missing

```
import com.netflix.astyanax.model.ConsistencyLevel;
```

But in reality, the astynax project that is used for it is already retired, and shouldn't be used.

Comment: Ok ..Thanks Sir

Comment: Sir where I put asyncCasaandra jar in opentsdb directory?
Actually I want to us  Cassandra as backend db for opentsdb.
As we know, in opentsdb default db is HBase.
But I do not want to use HBase, means I want to use Cassandra.
So I have build a asynccassandra jar, but I do not know where I should copy this asynccassandra jat in opentsdb?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not expert in the OpenTSDB... Did you check this documentation http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/user_guide/backends/cassandra.html ? But from what I see, OpenTSDB isn't very good use case for Cassandra...

Comment: Yes I checked this ...but it does not describe where to put AsyncCassandra jar in opentsDB.

I have built a assynccassandra jar which will enable opentsdb to write into Cassandra. And I also have made those changes in opendb's config file. But I don't know where should I put this asynccassandra jar in opendb.